# Why isn't my ResourceBundleControlProvider being loaded?

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I thought I would use the new `ResourceBundleControlProvider` framework in Java 8 to fix something which Oracle themselves will never fix - the default encoding used when reading resource bundles.

So I made a control:

```
package com.acme.resources;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AcmeResourceBundleControl extends ResourceBundle.Control
{
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format,
                                    ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO");
    }
}
```

Then I made a provider:

```
package com.acme.resources;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider;

public class AcmeResourceBundleControlProvider implements ResourceBundleControlProvider
{
    private static final ResourceBundle.Control CONTROL = new AcmeResourceBundleControl();

    @Override
    public ResourceBundle.Control getControl(String baseName)
    {
        if (baseName.startsWith("com.acme."))
        {
            return CONTROL;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in META-INF/services/java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider:

```
com.acme.resources.AcmeResourceBundleControlProvider
```

Then I just tried to run our application from IDEA and I find that it never loads my provider (otherwise the exception would be raised.)

I have checked the names and they all seem to match up. I have checked the compiler output directory IDEA is using and it does contain the service file. I wrote a simple test program which just tries to look up the service:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (ResourceBundleControlProvider provider :
         ServiceLoader.load(ResourceBundleControlProvider.class))
    {
        System.out.println(provider.getClass());
    }
}
```

This does print out one entry which is the name of my implementation class. So the issue is *not* in the service file.

If I breakpoint inside ResourceBundle, I seem to be able to access the custom provider class. Initial forays into the debugger show that ServiceLoader isn't finding any implementations, but I can't figure out why. I'm sure there is some dodgy class loader magic going on which results in not loading my class. :(

Some scary documentation on [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/ResourceBundleControlProvider.html) makes it sound like it might have to be installed as a global extension. If that really is the case, it's a bit of a shame, because it seemed like a useful way to override the default (and in my opinion broken) behaviour. But I also read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/serviceproviders/resourcebundlecontrolprovider.html) on the matter and it didn't seem to be describing anything like that (unless the good behaviour was pulled out of Java 8 at the very last minute and the docs are out of date!)

Comment: What happens if you manually jar your app and then run the jar (ensuring directory structure)? I'm not an IDEA user, but I'm just thinking that maybe `META-INF/services/java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider` isn't on the runtime classpath, or it isn't being inspected.

Comment: Running from a jar doesn't seem to be calling my provider either. So it's weird, ServiceLoader.load() from *my* code finds the provider, but ResourceBundle.getBundle() doesn't, which seems to defeat the purpose of having the provider framework at all. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial does state that the JAR containing the [ResourceBundleControlProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) must be in the JVM's system extension directory. Section 6 of the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/serviceproviders/resourcebundlecontrolprovider.html#run-rbcptest) describes the requirement:

> java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -cp build RBCPTest
>
> When you install a Java extension, you typically put the JAR file of the extension in the lib/ext directory of your JRE. However, this command specifies the directory that contains Java extensions with the system property java.ext.dirs.

The JavaDoc for [ServiceLoader.loadInstalled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#loadInstalled-java.lang.Class-) also states that providers on the application's class path are ignored.

Comment: Yeah, so it seems. So another feature we were eagerly waiting for has been crippled to the point that nobody can use it. How nice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the java.util.ResourceBundle that comes with the JVM does a ServiceLoader.loadInstalled(ResourceBundleControlProvider.class) to obtain a list of providers in the static initializer, and uses the thus obtained list ever after.